# Macro VBA code to select a row X row below the one selected

Tags: vba, excel, row

I need your help.

I have a worksheet to update from another one.
Basically is it all the months and the rows are moving from a month to a month because same month LY disappear and same month next year is a rota.
However on this worksheet the format is fixed depending it is 28 or 31 days per month.

so I have a macro asking to enter the row number for Jan :

```
 RowSelected1 = InputBox("Enter row Jan")
 Rows(RowSelected1).Select
 Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row & ":DJ" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
```

But instead to do that for every month, I would like from RowSelected1 (January) to count 44 rows and copy this 44th row with the same code as above.

And then count again 44 and copy

etc etc

Do you have anything to help me on that?

Many thanks
M.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
Rows(RowSelected1 + 44).Select
Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row & ":DJ" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim i As Integer

RowSelected1 = InputBox("Enter row Jan")
Rows(RowSelected1).Select

For i = 1 to 11
Rowselected1 = Rowselected1 + 44
'Do whatever you want to do using Rowselected1 to refer to the row
Next i
```

Alternatively you can use Offset in a loop over the months:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(44,0).Select
```